# c# inheritance & chaining question

Tags: c#, inheritance, chaining

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual Parent me()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
}
```

new Child().me() is returning a Parent object.  What do i need to have it return the Child object itself (without using extension and generic)??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `me` method is returning a reference to the actual object, which is of the type `Child`, but the type of the reference is of the type `Parent`.

So, what you have is a reference of the type `Parent` that points to an object of the type `Child`. You can use that to access any members that the `Child` class inherits from the `Parent` class. To access the members of the `Child` class you have to cast the reference to the type `Child`:

```
Child c = (Child)someObject.me();
```

You could make the `me` method return a `Child` reference and do the casting inside the method, but then it will of course not work to return a reference to a `Parent` object. If you don't use generics, each method can only have one return type. Even if you override the method in the `Child` class, it still has to return the same data type as in the `Parent` class.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said no generics...

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual Parent me()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    new public Child me ()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Also, as Darin said, it is the compile-time type that is off, not the actual object (instance) being returned.

Answer (score 1):

No, `(new Child()).me()` returns a `Child` object, but the *expression* has *type* `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

No, `new Child().me()` is returning an instance of `Child`:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Child().me()); // prints Child
```

For compile-time safety you will need generics.